# Keep chrome open but close console

Tags: selenium

I want to keep chrome open and close the console. I've read that webdriver.service.stop() will do this but I can't get it to work. I've tried importing several things from selenium that are namec service but I stil get selenium.webdriver has no attribute'service'. The last two imports are unused. Currently when I run the script without pycharmt the console starts and if I close it after it runs it closes the chrome window as well. I would like to not have to manually close the console window.

This is my updated code as of 2019-03-15:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common import service
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import service




chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.set_capability("detach", True)
DynamoForum = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)



DynamoForum.get("https://forum.dynamobim.com/")
Parent_window = DynamoForum.window_handles[0]
login = DynamoForum.find_element_by_class_name("header-buttons").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(DynamoForum, 20)

window_child = DynamoForum.window_handles[1]
DynamoForum.switch_to.window(window_child)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "userName"))).send_keys("abc@abc.com")
DynamoForum.find_element_by_id("verify_user_btn").click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("abc")
DynamoForum.find_element_by_id("btnSubmit").click()

try:
     DynamoForum.service.stop()
except AttributeError:
     pass
```

Below is the old Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common import service
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import service


chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

DynamoForum = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
DynamoForum.get("https://forum.dynamobim.com/")
Parent_window = DynamoForum.window_handles[0]
login = DynamoForum.find_element_by_class_name("header-buttons").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(DynamoForum, 20)

window_child = DynamoForum.window_handles[1]
DynamoForum.switch_to.window(window_child)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"userName"))).send_keys("abc@abc.com")
DynamoForum.find_element_by_id("verify_user_btn").click()


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"password"))).send_keys("abc")
DynamoForum.find_element_by_id("btnSubmit").click()

webdriver.service.stop()
```

This is the error I'm getting. This has been solved by changing webdriver.serive.stop to DynamoForum.service.stop.

```
C:/Users/cjr/PycharmProjects/DynamoForum/DynamoForum.py:13: 
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  DynamoForum = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cjr/PycharmProjects/DynamoForum/DynamoForum.py", line 29, 
in <module>
    webdriver.service.stop()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'service'
```

Comment: change the last line to DynamoForum.service.stop()

Comment: I tried that and it closed both.

Comment: Any way to close the pythond console but leave the chrome up?

Answer (score 0):

**This is workaround only**
I know this is not the correct approach, but for time being you can replace the last line with below. This will pass the execution, but keep your browser open after execution.

```
try:
    webdriver.service.stop()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Let me know if this is helpful. Will keep digging into this in the mean time.

Comment: Both still closed.

Comment: Could this have something to do with how I'm running it? I created a shortcut to the .py on my desktop.

Comment: hmm, not sure. But the solution, I provided is tested and it's working. Have you tried to run directly from pycharm and see the behavior?

Comment: In pycharm the script runs without the console obviously and when it finishes chrome closes. In the past when I had nothing there the window would stay open.

Comment: `chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.set_capability("detach", True)
DynamoForum = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`I've refined my code a bit but it is still closing. Am I using detach incorrectly? @supputuri